# Column names are incorrectly Mapped

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-data-lake, azure-data-lake-gen2, data-lake

I was trying to pull/load data from on-prem data lake to azure data lake using Azure Data Factory.

I was just giving query to pull all the columns. My Sink is Azure Data Lake Gen2.

[image]

But my Column names are coming wrong in source and sink.
My columns name in on-prem data lake are like **user_id**, **lst_nm**, etc. But in Azure it is like **user_tbl.user_id**, **user_tbl.lst_nm** , **etc** Here **user_tbl** is my table name.
I don't want table name getting added to columns.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Azure won't add the table name itself to the columns, can you check the output of select query that you are sending to source using preview data in ADF, that will show you the actual column names ADF is getting from source and if it doesn't have the table name prefixed then please check if your ADLS Gen 2 destination folder already have any file, if yes then remove the file and try running the pipeline again

Comment: Using preview data also same. But in source column names are fine.

Comment: ok, if Preview Data is also showing table name in prefix then I would suggest you to check the Dataset once, as I can see from the screenshot you have used Hive Dataset, can you check if you have already selected a table name in the dataset?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `Copy` activity, use `Data flow` transformation which allows you to change the Column name at destination dynamically.

Or you can also use `Move and transform` activity which also allows you to change column name. Refer official tutorial: [Dynamically set column names in data flows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/tutorial-data-flow-dynamic-columns)

Also check [ADF Mapping Data Flows: Create rules to modify column names](https://kromerbigdata.com/2019/05/24/adf-mapping-data-flows-create-rules-to-modify-column-names/)